# PHP alternative syntax not working

Tags: php, frameworks, syntax-error

PHP alternative syntax is not working in the website i'm working on. it's using what appears to be a home-rolled templating framework solution (as i can't really discern which one it might be). that is making extensive use of PHP short tags, like...

```
<? some code goes here ?>
```

the problem is - in the templates i want to have big blocks of HTML that either get shown or not shown based on a simple *IF* statement, and it would be so much cleaner to do this...

```
<?php if (some condition === true) { ?>
lots of HTML tags and content here
<?php } ?>
```

...(like in WordPress) than to do everything via *echo* or *print*.

here are the errors i'm getting before...

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in
/some-directory/Lib/Fw/PageController.php(330) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

...and after...

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in
/some-directory/Lib/Fw/PageController.php(330) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

...that block of code.

can anybody lend some advice on how to "fix" this framework to allow PHP alternative syntax?

Comment: *note - i would like to add that i have also tried the _other_ form of alternative syntax using the ":" and "endif;" instead of braces (example in Vladimir's answer below).

Comment: eval may possibly not play nice. Can you post a sample of where the error is thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<?php if (some condition === true): ?>
lots of HTML tags and content here
<?php endif; ?>
```

The same goes for for, foreach and elses:

> http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: Hi Vladimir - thanks for the help, but i guess i should have mentioned that i tried that too. i'll add a comment to my original post so that others know.